# n-Layered Design Confusion

Tags: n-layer

Can anyone provide me with a web link that shows a correct approach of n-Layered design with example source-code in VS2005 and C#?

I am confused in one point, If I am creating layers like the following:

```
   UI
   |
Business Logic
   |
  Data Access
```

then how can I achieve true OOP?

Coz In OOP all activities should be encapsulated within an Object.

According to my thought, this should be layered like this:

```
   UI
   |
Business Objects
   |
Business Logics
   |
Data Access
```

But when trying to design layers like this I experienced Circular Reference Problem.

One of my buddy told me that, he solved this problem with Reflection.

So what is the industry-standard approach in separating a c# application into layers?

And a burning question is, which layer hosts the OR-Mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[alt text http://amrelgarhy.com/files/uploads/9-1-2009%208-58-14%20PM.png](http://amrelgarhy.com/files/uploads/9-1-2009%208-58-14%20PM.png)

And Some times goes like this:

[alt text http://amrelgarhy.com/files/uploads/9-1-2009%208-59-14%20PM.png](http://amrelgarhy.com/files/uploads/9-1-2009%208-59-14%20PM.png)

So as you see in the 2 previous diagrams, the ORM located in the data access layer